# json serialization to refer schema

Tags: json, json.net

I am serializing an object to a json.

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item) 

public class Item
{
    public int name;
    public string category;
}

output 
[ 
    { 
      "Name": "Item1", 
      "category": "Free", 
     }, 
]
```

in the serialized string I want to have a ref to the schema defined for the json file

```
output 
[ 
    { 
      "$schema": "http://www.example.com/itemModel.json#",
      "Name": "Item1", 
      "category": "Free", 
     }, 
]
```

Comment: Why can't you just add the schema.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276928/use-json-net-to-generate-json-schema-with-extra-attributes

Comment: add the schema ? you mean to the Item class ? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have the schema already defined at the url http://www.example.com/itemModel.json#. I want a pointer to that in the json file I am creating.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71627502/18452174